# "То, чего не понимаете" или "то, что не понимаете"?

Tags: орфография

А как пишется правильно?
Я не понимаю.

Comment: Правильно и то и то. Спрашивайте лучше, в чём разница и когда что использовать.

Comment: "Лишь бы захейтить то, чего не понимаете." Это правильное написание или тут есть ошибки? Нужно ли заменить "чего" на "что" ?

Comment: Здесь "что" лучше на слух. Лучше сам вопрос обобщить, например: в чём разница между этими вариантами и в каких случаях они используются? Что-то подобное можете добавить в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать Р.п.:  *Лишь бы захейтить то, **чего (вообще) не понимаете**.*

Употребление Р.п.  связано с **отвлеченностью** местоимения "что", а также **полнотой отрицания** (не понимать предмет полностью, а не что-то конкретное в нем).

Сравнить:

(1) Понимать **что**: В.п., действие направлено на прямой объект.

(2) Не понимать ничего: Р.п., при отсутствии прямого объекта действие распространяется до его границ. В этом случае указано, что весь объект недоступен для понимания.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129231/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---------).

Answer (score 1):

Контекст нужен.

~1 ***То, что вы не понимаете простых вещей, это очень плохо.***
Тут только так.

~2 ***То, что/чего вы не понимаете, очень просто*** - тут возможны варианты, как и в других аналогичных фразах.
Этот случай исчерпывающе разобран у Sharon, не буду повторяться.
Могу только посоветовать: если не знаете, как правильно в вашем конкретном контексте (то есть не представляете, конкретный ли тут объект) , пишите ***"чего"*** - вероятность возникновения непонимания у читающего будет меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Эти слова взаимозаменяемы (корректно и то и то), но есть нюансы — что когда лучше.

*Чего* — про что-то глубокое, объёмное, обширное:
*Он не говорит о том, чего не понимает.* || Предлог О указывает на объёмность темы — поэтому "чего".

*Что* — про что-то узкое, конкретное:
*Он не спрашивает то, что не понимает.* || Отсутствие предлога О указывает на конкретность вопроса.

Поэтому для точного ответа необходимо знать, что именно там хейтили. Но "что" точно подходит, потому что нет предлога. Но и "чего" может подойти, если там хейтят в общем, без разбора, а не что-то конкретное.

Вариант "чего" более книжный, а "что" более разговорный. Учитывая, что "хейтить" разговорное, "что" как-то лучше подходит.

"Чего" может подразумевать "вообще":
*Лишь бы захейтить то, чего [вообще] не понимаете.* || А "вообще" в некоторой мере указывает на объёмность.

Самый подходящий смысл:
*Лишь бы захейтить то, что не понимаете должным образом.* || То есть не понимают как положено или понимают не так, как следует (из-за этого часто хейтят в интернете). Вряд ли они вообще ничего не понимают.